# how to covert uinteger to color or RGB

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, colors, rgb

I want to coloring the rectangle with some color in which the color values worth uinteger. Can I do that? or how to change the value uinteger to color or Rgb in vb.net? i use 4.5 .net framework.
please help me, thanks...

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To sf.Categories.Count - 1

        Dim category As MapWinGIS.ShapefileCategory = sf.Categories.Item(i)
        Dim icolor As UInteger = scheme.GraduatedColor((i + 1) / sf.Categories.Count)
        'MsgBox(icolor)
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(icolor) 'eror
    Next
```

ex: i have 16744576, then i search in google RGB value is rgb(255,128,128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ColorTranslator class for this:

```
    Dim oleColor As Integer = 16744576

    ' Translate oleColor to a GDI+ Color structure. 
    Dim myColor As Color = ColorTranslator.FromOle(oleColor)

    ' Confirm the RGB values
    Debug.WriteLine(myColor.ToString()) ' Color [A=255, R=128, G=128, B=255]
```

Comment: The `FromOle` method translates from an BGR value, not an RGB value. You get `[A=255, R=128, G=128, B=255]` instead of `[A=255, R=255, G=128, B=128]`.

Comment: @Guffa - yes this is what I put in my answer. I believe that MapWindow colours are in fact OLE Colors

Answer (score 0):

The value is an RGB value. You can convert it to an ARGB value by adding the alpha channel value 255 (FF in hex), then convert to a color:

```
Panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(icolor Or &HFF000000)
```

You can also convert the number directly to a color (treating the RGB value as if it was an ARGB value), but that will have an alpha value of zero so it will be transparent. You can then create a color from that color that has a specific alpha value:

```
Panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.FromArgb(icolor))
```